# How do I find out the websocket url of my server?

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, server, openshift

I am trying to host a web app on Openshift. I am using a websocket that handles all the connections. However,I am not sure what value to enter for my socket url. I have a .js file that reads:

```
...
// socket connection url and port
var socket_url = '192.168.8.102';
var port = '8080';

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form_submit, #form_send_message").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        join();
    });
});

var webSocket;

/**
 * Connecting to socket
 */
function join() {
    // Checking person name
    if ($('#input_name').val().trim().length <= 0) {
        alert('Enter your name');
    } else {
        name = $('#input_name').val().trim();

        $('#prompt_name_container').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            // opening socket connection
            openSocket();
        });
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Will open the socket connection
 */
function openSocket() {
    // Ensures only one connection is open at a time
    if (webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a new instance of the websocket
    webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + socket_url + ":" + port
            + "/WebMobileGroupChatServer/chat?name=" + name);

....
```

When i test it locally,it works perfectly using my local ip address of 192.168.8.102 as the socket_url. However, if I were to put my program up for online hosting,what value of socket_url should I enter instead? My domain name is http://jbosslew-weihao.rhcloud.com/

When I test it locally using tomcat apache server, the domain name is 
http://192.168.8.102:8080/WebMobileGroupChatServer/

How do I find out the socket url of my server on openshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html you need to bind it to the port `8000` for regular access or to port `8443` for secure access

So your websockets url would be one of the following:

ws://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8000/path
wss://app-domain.rhcloud.com:8443/path